# What does "The children were spared (from) the virus" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/spare_2):
**(1)** *The children were spared **from** the virus*.

What does (1) mean?
Does it mean (2), (3) or (4)?:
**(2)** *The children didn't contract the virus*.
**(3)** *The children contracted the virus but, after that, were cured*.
**(4)** *The children contracted the virus but it didn't cause any serious harm to their health*.

How will the meaning change if we remove "*from*"?:
**(5)** *The children were spared the virus*.

Comment: I think most people would under stand it to mean that they didn't catch it. If they had caught it but escaped serious harm, it would be _The children were spared the worst effects of the virus._

Comment: @KateBunting How will the meaning change if we remove "from"?: _The children were spared the virus_. Thanks.

Comment: It won't change.

Answer (score 1):

I think the examples in OP's cited dictionary aren't very carefully curated. We [don't normally](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=were%20spared%20the%2Cwere%20spared%20from%20the&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) include ***from*** between *to be spared* and whatever bad thing the subject didn't have to undergo...

[image]

The specific collocation ***spared** [from] **the virus*** doesn't occur often enough to chart in Google NGrams, but ***spared** [from] **the disease*** is a close enough alternative...

[image]

---

The *meaning* is the same with or without ***from***, but at least *some* people (including me, obviously! :) will think it's a bit "clunky" to include it.